# What is this called: Melting? Pivoting? Reshaping?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a question about using pandas and ggplot in Python, but an R answer would also be very much appreciated.

I am trying to plot some timeseries data that look somewhat like what's shown below. X, Y, Z are well-plate ids (names of experiments), and 0,1,2 are different times. I want to be able to plot the time course as a line graph both in different panes/subplots/facets, and in the same facet but with different colors.

```
   X    Y    Z
0  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3
2  2.1  2.2  2.3
```

I know that pandas combined with ggplot would let me say

```
from ggplot import *
ggplot(aes(x='T', y='value', color='well'), data = df) + geom_line()
```

or

```
from ggplot import *
ggplot(aes(x='T', y='value'), data = df) + geom_line() + facet_grid(x='well')
```

if df looked like this

```
well  T   value
X     0   0.1
X     1   1.1
X     2   2.1
Y     0   0.2
Y     1   1.2
Y     2   2.2
Z     0   0.3
Z     1   1.3
Z     2   2.3
```

, with rows not necessarily in that order.

My question is, how do I make the data frame above into the data frame below the code, and what is this operation called? Again, I'm mainly interested in pandas and ggplot in Python, but an answer as to how this could be done in R would also be very helpful.

I would also appreciate it if someone can recommend a good source to learn about doing such things with data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called reshaping a a dataframe with methods such as pivot or melting and can include stack and unstack, pivot_table and various other methods.

## To go from 'wide' to 'long'

```
print(df)

     X    Y    Z
0  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3
2  2.1  2.2  2.3
```

You can reshape into a long dataframe with such methods as `stack` and `reset_index`:

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['T','well','value']
print(df2)

   T well  value
0  0    X    0.1
1  0    Y    0.2
2  0    Z    0.3
3  1    X    1.1
4  1    Y    1.2
5  1    Z    1.3
6  2    X    2.1
7  2    Y    2.2
8  2    Z    2.3
```

Or using `melt`:

```
df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'T'}).melt(id_vars='T').sort_values(by='T')

   T well  value
0  0    X    0.1
3  0    Y    0.2
6  0    Z    0.3
1  1    X    1.1
4  1    Y    1.2
7  1    Z    1.3
2  2    X    2.1
5  2    Y    2.2
8  2    Z    2.3
```

## To go from 'long' to 'wide'

```
print(df2)

T well  value
0  0    X    0.1
3  0    Y    0.2
6  0    Z    0.3
1  1    X    1.1
4  1    Y    1.2
7  1    Z    1.3
2  2    X    2.1
5  2    Y    2.2
8  2    Z    2.3
```

Using `pivot`:

```
df2.pivot(index='T',columns='well')

     value          
well     X    Y    Z
T                   
0      0.1  0.2  0.3
1      1.1  1.2  1.3
2      2.1  2.2  2.3
```

Using `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df2.set_index(['T','well']).unstack()

     value          
well     X    Y    Z
T                   
0      0.1  0.2  0.3
1      1.1  1.2  1.3
2      2.1  2.2  2.3
```

Using `pivot_table`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df2,aggfunc='mean',index='T',columns='well')

     value          
well     X    Y    Z
T                   
0      0.1  0.2  0.3
1      1.1  1.2  1.3
2      2.1  2.2  2.3
```

Comment: WOW. I think I just tread into some deep waters.

This is awesome. Thank you. Now I know where to start.

Comment: What is the advantage of stack vs melt? 
And pivot_table vs unstack vs pivot?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df1 = df.T.stack().reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_0': 'well', 'level_1': 'T', 0: 'value'})


    well    T   value
0   X       0   0.1
1   X       1   1.1
2   X       2   2.1
3   Y       0   0.2
4   Y       1   1.2
5   Y       2   2.2
6   Z       0   0.3
7   Z       1   1.3
8   Z       2   2.3
```